# Using header window to explore python

Tags: python, interface

I'm trying to (re)learn python scripting with Blender for a project I'm working on. It's made leaps and bounds in progress since I used it last, especially with the display of API commands in the pull down window.

Unfortunately, the best documentation I can find on it is [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6409/repetitive-tasks-using-python/6410#6410). From playing around with the text, it seems to have the ability to select lines (right click), and to copy them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>), and nothing else.

Now, I understand it isn't meant to do much, but are there any other shortcuts or tricks for using it? Particularly copying text, selecting lines one at a time gets old pretty quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you have the right click mouse to select a line, you can select a block of line with <kbd>B</kbd> then click and drag for select or middle mouse click and drag for un-select. And you can select and un-select all the line with <kbd>A</kbd>.

You can delete all selected lines by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>.

As far as I know, the only way to copy a line is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

My tip for selecting only one line is, if you have other lines selected, do <kbd>A</kbd> for un-select all and then copy your line.

Last thing, for navigating you can use the middle mouse wheel but you can also use the middle mouse wheel click then click and drag.

Comment: Thanks.  Playing around with it, it looks like b-shift will unselect lines as well.  Just curious, did you find this on the wiki or in the release notes?

Comment: I use blender every day for scripting, I found them and now use them. But it's the same hotkey than in the 3D view for example.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around some more and I found how to list all the shortcuts, for any window.

- Go to user preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, or *File > User Preferences*).
- Click on the input tab.
- Options for each window are displayed, click on the arrow next to info.
- All the keyboard commands are shown, clicking on the arrow again gives options to change it.
  The only shortcut not already stated is R, which replays the last action (seems to work as <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on my computer)