# Seeing Construction History for use in python

Tags: python

I know that operators can be copied for scripting by ctrl-c if you mouse through whatever menu item you are at.

What I was wondering is if there is a way to see the construction history. In Maya's scripting panel you can turn on construction history, and then as you select an item or press any operator (like create polygon cube) it prints out the internal construction code to a window.
(That actual prints Mel scripting for Maya).

I am sure the construction history is stored in some data object, so another spin on the question could be phrased . What is the name of this object and can I run a print loop through it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pull down the 'Info' panel at the top of the blender window to reveal the code for operators that have been run:

[image]

Here I have deleted an object, added a cube and then rotated the cube.

Comment: @SteveWeber Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6409/repetitive-tasks-using-python/6410#6410